# "Enable Tab Search" not in chrome://flags

Tags: google-chrome

I just noticed a new icon in the title bar of my Chrome windows, a circle with a down arrow in it. This is apparently a new, experimental "Search Tabs" feature.

According to [this site](https://www.howtogeek.com/722640/how-to-enable-or-disable-the-tab-search-icon-in-chrome/) I should be able to remove this by going to chrome://flags and changing the "Enable Tab Search" setting. But I can't find the setting on that page. Is there some other way I can disable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is addressed in the Chrome bug report
[Issue 1215708: Option to remove tab search](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215708).

This issue is labelled as "Type: Bug-Regression", which gives hope that
making the icon "Tab Search" permanent may not have been intentional,
so there is still hope for the future.

Your best option is voting for this issue and waiting.

If you are on Windows, you may switch to Microsoft Edge, which is almost
identical to Chrome, but doesn't have this feature.

Comment: Thanks. I'm on a Mac, so Edge is not an option.

Comment: Edge is also [available on macOS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge).

Comment: I've installed Edge, maybe I'll play around with it to see how I like it.

Answer (score 0):

The "down arrow" search came out in April. At this point (June) it is not really experimental any more.

For many people, the feature cannot be disabled (I think that includes you and me).

For fewer people, it can be disabled.

In another month (just say), it will be made permanent. It seem quite out of the way if you do not need to use it.

I suggest ignoring it.

You can also try / use Chromium Edge. It is much like Chrome fundamentally but still uses Find on Page for some of its searching

I find either way to be workable with no need to disable.

Aggregate data collection is very common so the exact method of search presentation does not really change that.

Comment: It sounds like they may be gathering statistics that will inform whether they'll make it optional in the future.

Comment: Chromium Edge works a bit differently but still both easy to use. Chrome, Google, Edge, Windows, Firefox et all gather aggregated statistics. You are not personally identified in this endeavour.

Comment: This minor issue is not enough for me to switch browsers from something I'm familiar and happy with.

Comment: You can stick with Chrome. The little button does not get in the way at all. I have and use both.

Comment: I know. It's a minor thing, and if I can't get rid of it that's the way it is.

Comment: That is because the newest version of Chrome has installed it. It may change, but not likely.

Comment: I know it's new. the article I linked to says it was added in April.

Comment: I'm surprised they removed it from the experimental flags in only 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly this feature cannot be disabled in chrome not even in the beta. in the newest version it changes the icon when you change the flag.

From this (flag on):

[image: Flag on]

to this (flag off):

[image: Flag off]

Brave beta has an option to disable tab search that's what I'm using instead of looking at it.

Comment: I just upgraded Chrome and the icon changed to the arrow without the circle, but there's still no flag.