# Remove the Tab Search Arrow from Chrome without using flags?

Tags: google-chrome

Chrome seems to enjoy adding new annoyances to it's browser and removing the flags to disable them. There's no flag to remove the Tab Search anymore, so how do I remove it from Chrome without the flag?

Answer (score 1):

The "Search tabs" button was previously an experimental option
and had a flag to turn it off.
However, now it has gone mainstream, so cannot any more be
turned off.

There is now a new experimental flag that will enable the (quote)
"new desktop design", which does not include this button,
but which also changes the whole look of Chrome.

To enable this new look, enable the flag "Chrome Refresh 2023" at
`chrome://flags/#chrome-refresh-2023` and restart Chrome.

You may read more about this new look in the article
[How to Enable or Disable New UI in Google Chrome](https://www.askvg.com/tip-how-to-enable-or-disable-new-ui-in-google-chrome/).

Here is what this new look is like :

[image]

Comment: Wonderful. now that stupid arrow is no longer in the way

Comment: The Tab Search button remains, it just moves to the left a little...

Comment: @itsmejoeeey: Experimental flag may have different effect on different versions of Chrome, and might even disappear in the future. If they work, they may solve problems, but they might also disappear without notice.

Answer (score 0):

There [used to be an option to disable this](https://superuser.com/q/1655506/291509) in `chrome://flags` until it "regressed" / was removed.

The related issues [[1]](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1215708) [[2]](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1240595) on the bug tracker are now closed.

It doesn't seem the Chromium team have any desire to allow you to enable/disable this part of the UI. As @harrymc said "there is currently no known method for removing it."

Consider using Microsoft Edge or Brave (which are both Chromium based), as both may allow you to disable this feature.