# How to remove the Chrome's arrow-pointing-down button on upper left that was added in version 118.0.5993.89?

Tags: google-chrome

I want to remove this new arrow-pointing-down button that opens a list of tabs. I kinda think we already had the similar button in chrome and if I'm not wrong, I could turn it off. Today is new update and this button appeared. Is there a way to remove it or are we stuck with it like with "Side Panel" button on the right side?

[image]

Comment: I got a question "Do you want to try Chrome New Look"  My answer: No.  Try this post to change your setting back.      https://bugartisan.medium.com/disable-the-new-chrome-ui-round-in-2023-db168271f71e

Comment: I just updated, and I don't see that button moved. It's still top-right.

Comment: I do not see it either but I did get a question about new look.

Comment: Author:   You may need to just adapt, or possibly create a new Chrome Profile.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Enable Tab Search" not in chrome://flags](https://superuser.com/questions/1655506/enable-tab-search-not-in-chrome-flags)

Comment: You might have to spend some time to learn about Chrome Experiments, distribution channels, and chrome://flags

Comment: It amazes me that they still haven't learn that when thay add anything to an accustomed layout to offer the possibility to disable it.

Answer (score 4):

go to the `chrome://flags` and disable this one:

```
Chrome Refresh 2023 New Tab Button
Enables the variations of the new tab button for chrome refresh 2023. – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Fuchsia, Lacros

#chrome-refresh-2023-ntb
```

If you want to disable all "New Chrome webUI", go to the:

```
Chrome WebUI Refresh 2023
Enables Chrome Refresh 2023 styles for various WebUI surfaces. – Mac, Windows, Linux, ChromeOS, Fuchsia, Lacros

#chrome-webui-refresh-2023
```